# How to deploy AngularJS app using nginx + docker to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, docker

So I'm in the process of deploying an AngularJS app to an AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance.

I've successfully configured the build requirements, which involves uploading a `Dockerrun.aws.json` file that's configured to access an S3 storage bucket which in turn contains the `.dockercfg` file, used for accessing my private Docker repo.

Everything builds successfully, and nginx runs. I get the default "Welcome to nginx on Debian!" message.

So the only thing I'm having an issue with is now pointing the build of my AngularJS app to the active/home page (where the "Welcome.." screen appears.)

All of the app's contents are stored inside /build, from the root directory of the project, which is where my `Dockerfile` is contained.

From what I've gathered so far I think I need to go along the lines of:

```
FROM nginx
COPY /build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Placed inside the `Dockerfile`, however those particular commands don't work.

I'm sure it's relatively trivial achieving what I'm hoping to, but having scoured various articles and documentations I can't find a simple answer. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I actually found the proper solution to this, in typical fashion, a few minutes after I'd written this question.

Kapott's answer is also along the right lines, however it's not quite there, so for good measure here's the answer:

```
COPY <directory_containing_app_index> /var/www/html/
```

The public html is stored inside the nginx directory `/var/www/html/`. I copied `/usr/share/nginx/html/` from the [nginx docker page](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), although I didn't expect that to be correct, it seemed from the explanation that was the way to do it.

Comment: COPY will copy a directory as well, and should generally be preferred to ADD.

Comment: I did wonder that, I actually said that because of something I read, I didn't check COPY beforehand since it worked anyway with ADD, I'll amend my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Try omitting the first slash in the Dockerfile's copy command, so it takes the path relative to the Dockerfile:

`COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/`