# How to deploy Angular.js to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: angularjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the simple way to deploy an AngularJS app into Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.? Should We use a Docker container ? or a simple node.js app will do the trick ?

Thank you in advance
Eduardo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy AngularJS app using nginx + docker to Elastic Beanstalk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491203/how-to-deploy-angularjs-app-using-nginx-docker-to-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question. I figured out that deploying Angular.JS app to Elastic Beanstalk is not a good choice.
I created an S3 bucket and set it for static website hosting, easier and more elegant solution